# Ufw allow http traffic out

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

I have a server machine with ubuntu 20 on wich i've installed `ufw`, this are my rules

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     LIMIT       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere                   # allow SSH connections in
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                   # allow https traffic update
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
587                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere                   # godaddy IMAP
995                        ALLOW       Anywhere                   # godaddy POP3
465                        ALLOW       Anywhere                   # godaddy SMTP
SMTPTLS                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
25 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)              # allow SSH connections in
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # allow https traffic update
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
587 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
993 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # godaddy IMAP
995 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # godaddy POP3
465 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # godaddy SMTP
SMTPTLS (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # allow DNS calls out
123                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # allow NTP out
80/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # allow HTTPS traffic out
43/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # allow whois
25                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # allow MAIL out
SMTPTLS                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # open TLS port 465 for use with SMPT to send e-mails
21/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   # allow FTP traffic out
53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              # allow DNS calls out
123 (v6)                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              # allow NTP out
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              # allow HTTPS traffic out
43/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              # allow whois
25 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              # allow MAIL out
SMTPTLS (v6)               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              # open TLS port 465 for use with SMPT to send e-mails
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)              # allow FTP traffic out
```

I'm trying to make a `curl` request to another server

```
curl http://my.ip:5000
```

But this command gives a "Connection timed out" error.

I thought that the problem was `ufw` not allowing HTTP traffic out so I enabled port 80 to allow traffic in and out, but didn't work. If I totally disable `ufw` the `curl` command works correctly and returns the response but I cannot figure out what rule i need to add to make it work with `ufw` active.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've set the default OUT rule to DENY?

You've opened up for traffic to port 80/tcp, but you're trying to connect to port 5000 on the server.
Try:

```
ufw allow out 5000/tcp
```